# Redirect http request for my application to external website in spring webflow

Tags: java, spring-webflow

I want to redirect people accessing my website to external website. I used this code in my flow.xml

```
<view-state id="redirect" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:#{http://google.com}"/>
```

I also tried adding this code to the method in my action class, yet I can't make the redirection happen

```
context.getExternalContext().requestExternalRedirect("http://google.com");
```

I get the error shown below when doing so:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the
>   response has been committed] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the
>   response has been committed

After going through the document I realized that we can use direct url as

```
<view-state id="redirect" view="externalRedirect:http://google.com"/>
```

Yet I seem to make no progress with the output.

Answer (score 1):

change your `<view-state>` into an `<end-state>` :

```
<end-state id="redirect" view="externalRedirect:http://google.com"/>
```

Comment: I removed the code for redirection i used in the action class and used the end-state but I do not see the redirection happening.

Comment: I tested it again and it's working fine. can you post the rest of your flow.xml?